# python asyncio run_forever or while True

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Should I replace `while True` in my code (without asyncio) or should I use asyncio event loop to accomplish the same result.

Currently I work on some kind "worker" that is connected to zeromq, receive some data and then performs some request (http) to external tool(server). Everything is written in *normal* blocking IO. Does it makes sense to use asyncio event loop to get rid of `while True: ...`?

In future it might be rewritten fully in asyncio, but now I'm afraid to start with asyncio.

i'm new with asyncio and not all part of this library are clear for me :)

Thx :)

Comment: If you're going to try to use `asyncio`, you should just completely rewrite the program using `aiozmq` and other `asyncio`-friendly libraries. Trying to mix blocking libraries with the asyncio event loop, especially if you're just doing it to remove a `while True:` loop, it usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to start writing asyncio code with a library that doesn't support it, you can use [BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor).

This allows you to submit a callable to a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) or a [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) and get the result asynchronously. The default executor is a thread pool of 5 threads.

Example:

```
# Python 3.4
@asyncio.coroutine
def some_coroutine(*some_args, loop=None):
    while True:
        [...]
        result = yield from loop.run_in_executor(
            None,  # Use the default executor
            some_blocking_io_call, 
            *some_args)
        [...]

# Python 3.5
async def some_coroutine(*some_args, loop=None):
    while True:
        [...]
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(
            None,  # Use the default executor
            some_blocking_io_call, 
            *some_args)
        [...]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = some_coroutine(*some_arguments, loop=loop)
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
```

Comment: How would You change the code to run `some_coroutine` forever? You would go with simple `while True:` or with other maybe asyncio way?

Comment: @qwetty Having a `while True` inside a coroutine is perfectly fine, as long as you perform an asynchronous call inside. Check the [examples](https://github.com/python/asyncio/tree/master/examples) out, [hello_coroutine](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/examples/hello_coroutine.py) for instance.

Comment: Thank You. That's what I need. Confirmation about while :)